# Cannot change graphic driver. All options are greyed out. (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS)

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, xorg, fglrx

I was changing my graphics driver at Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

I tried X.org, fglrx and fglrx-updates, and they were fine until for some reason I couldn't change it anymore and the performance now is terrible. It reads "Continue using a manually installed driver"

See below the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Please re-attach the screen-shot, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gcnYw.png) url is not working.

Comment: To me it opens fine.  Nevertheless here is another link: http://imgur.com/qlt0vbn

Answer (score 0):

So far,

I tried:

sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*"

and the options were not greyed out anymore. I chose fglrx and it seems to work now.